# Stop execution route

Tags: apache-camel

how can I stop execution specific route on exception?

currently I am using spliter with `</stop>` but this only stop current loop.

I want to completly stop execution but don't stop route

@edit

```
<route>
    <from uri=activemq:queue:message" />

    <split>
        <xpath> some xpath here by id </xpath>

        <when>
            <xquery>some xquery here </xquery>
             <throwException exceptionType="com.project.exception"
                                            message="exception"/>
            <stop/>
        </when>
    </split>
</route>
```

but it only stops current loop not whole route flow. I mean if it stops loop number 3 then it will start from 4

Comment: Add some pseudo route for more understanding, and start please marking answers in your questions as right or comment them that they didn't helped. Other users with same questions as yours will found your topics useful.

Comment: Add the stopOnException=true to `<split>`

Comment: Thank you for answer, but what If I want to stop execution on specific exception?

Comment: So use [doTry](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/try-catch-finally.html), hide exceptions and re-throw specific one.